# Convert Set to JSONArray in Java 8

Tags: java

Can this be optimized for Java 8 and can it be more efficient? I am using streams and lambdas.

```
public String LanguageString(Set<Locale> languageSet) throws Exception {
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
JSONObject tempj = new JSONObject();
JSONArray jArr = new JSONArray();
try {
  for (Locale locale : languageSet) {
    if (locale != null) {
      tempj = new JSONObject();
      tempj.put("lcode", locale.toLanguageTag());
      tempj.put("ldisplay", locale.getDisplayName());
      jArr.put(tempj);
    }
  }
  json.put("root", jArr);
} catch (JSONException e) {
  //
}
return json.toString();
}
```

Comment: Am I right in assuming that you're using `org.json:json`? Let me rephrase that... which JSON library are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You should not catch exceptions and discard them silently. This code has no chance of throwing an exception, therefore you should just let the exception bubble up and let someone else catch it. If it should ever happen.
- Your variable names don't express their intention. The word `temp` should not be used at all, you mix terminology between `languages` and `locale`. Sometimes you put the `j` at the beginning of the name, sometimes at the end; this is inconsistent.
- Declare your variables as late as possible (`json`).
- Declare your variables in the smallest possible scope (`tempj`).
- Method names in Java start with a lowercase letter.
- Don't declare `throws Exception` when your code doesn't actually do that.
- It is unusual that the `languages` set actually contains `null`. So in general you should leave out the `if (language != null)` check.

After following all these hints, the code may look like this:

```
public String createLanguagesJson(Set<Locale> languages) {
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
    for (Locale language : languages) {
        array.put(new JSONObject()
                .put("lcode", language.toLanguageTag())
                .put("ldisplay", language.getDisplayName()));
    }

    return new JSONObject()
            .put("root", array)
            .toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I really suggest to keep this implementation nearly as it is. It is clear and direct.

Maybe you decompose the method into two methods.

Maybe you reduce scope of one variable (tempj).

Maybe you rename some artefacts.

```
public String toJSONString(Set<Locale> languageSet) throws Exception {

    JSONObject root = new JSONObject();

    try {

        JSONArray localeAsJSONObjectArray = new JSONArray();

        for (Locale locale : languageSet) {
            if (locale != null) {
                localeAsJSONObjectArray.put(toJSONObject(locale));
            }
        }

        root.put("root", localeAsJSONObjectArray);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        //
    }

    return root.toString();
}

private JSONObject toJSONObject(Locale locale) {
    JSONObject localeAsJSONObject = new JSONObject();
    localeAsJSONObject.put("lcode", locale.toLanguageTag());
    localeAsJSONObject.put("ldisplay", locale.getDisplayName());
    return localeAsJSONObject;
}
```

Anything else will distort the intention. Introducing lambdas here will make me think that you want to make the algorithm fit to lambda as the direction should be vice versa: The used control structures should follow your algorithm.

You have to keep one thing in mind:

Lambdas and streams really make sense if you use ".parallelStream()" instead of ".stream()". Then your code will act in some parallel way with the Fork-Join-Thread-Pool and your code speeds up. Anything else is Old wine in new bottles. Occasionally lambdas seem to be more expressive. In other situations you will break your leg if you want to fit you algorithm to lambda and you loose expressiveness.

But to use ".parallelStream()" your code has to meet some not obvious requirements that is clear to those who already work with parallelism. Most of the time you are not able to simply change ".stream()" to ".prallelStream()". So most of the time you will not benefit from the new API.

If you still want to use lambdas I provide you an example that is surely not strcutral optimizied but that shows the elements to consider if you really want to benefit from parallelism.

```
public static String toJSONString(Set<Locale> languageSet) {

    JSONObject root = new JSONObject();

    JSONArray localeAsJSONObjectArray = new JSONArray();

    // synchronization, as putting may occur asynchronously. JSONArray itself is NOT synchronized. 

    Consumer<JSONObject> synchronizedJSONObjectAdder = jsonObject -> {

        synchronized (localeAsJSONObjectArray) {
            localeAsJSONObjectArray.put(jsonObject);
        }

    };

    // function that defines the transformation from a locale to a JSONObject.
    // no synchronization needed as every result only depends on the function parameter.

    Function<Locale, JSONObject> localeToJSONObjectFunction = locale -> {
        JSONObject localeAsJSONObject = new JSONObject();
        localeAsJSONObject.put("lcode", locale.toLanguageTag());
        localeAsJSONObject.put("ldisplay", locale.getDisplayName());

        // for debugging in which thread the transformation will be processed.

        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());

        return localeAsJSONObject;
    };

    // using parallel stream to address parallelism
    languageSet.parallelStream().filter(locale -> locale != null).map(localeToJSONObjectFunction).forEach(synchronizedJSONObjectAdder);

    root.put("root", localeAsJSONObjectArray);

    return root.toString();
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    toJSONString(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(Locale.getAvailableLocales())));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some enhancements:

- use more expressive variable names
- keep the variables in the smallest scope
- Don't use magic constants in your code

---

If you want to use Java 8 features it is straight forward. I'm assuming you're using `javax.json` library. There are neat implementation of builders.

```
private static final String ROOT_TAG = "root";
private static final String CODE_TAG = "lcode";
private static final String DISPLAY_TAG = "ldisplay";

public String languageString(Set<Locale> languageSet) {
  return languageSet.stream()
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .map(locale -> Json.createObjectBuilder()
      .add(CODE_TAG, locale.toLanguageTag())
      .add(DISPLAY_TAG, locale.getDisplayName()))
    .collect(builderToJsonString());
}

private Collector<JsonObjectBuilder, ?, String> builderToJsonString() {
  return Collector.of(Json::createArrayBuilder, JsonArrayBuilder::add, JsonArrayBuilder::addAll,
    builder -> Json.createObjectBuilder().add(ROOT_TAG, builder).build().toString());
}
```

As you can see:

- magic values are now constants
- I've used builders to build my JSON objects
- (It's possible to do the mapping stage in an extra method)
- A proper `Collector` which is capable of handling parallel `Stream`s

---

If you want to have a clean distinction between functionalities then your code might look like this:

```
private static final String ROOT_TAG = "root";
private static final String CODE_TAG = "lcode";
private static final String DISPLAY_TAG = "ldisplay";

public String languageString(Set<Locale> languageSet) {
  return languageSet.stream()
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .map(this::toJsonObject)
    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(objectBuilderToJsonArray(),
      this::wrapInJsonObjectAndToString));
}

private JsonObjectBuilder toJsonObject(Locale locale) {
  return Json.createObjectBuilder()
    .add(CODE_TAG, locale.toLanguageTag())
    .add(DISPLAY_TAG, locale.getDisplayName());
}

private Collector<JsonObjectBuilder, ?, JsonArrayBuilder> objectBuilderToJsonArray() {
  return Collector.of(Json::createArrayBuilder, JsonArrayBuilder::add, JsonArrayBuilder::addAll);
}

private String wrapInJsonObjectAndToString(JsonArrayBuilder builder) {
  return Json.createObjectBuilder().add(ROOT_TAG, builder).build().toString();
}
```